# Flutter web- disable spacebar to scroll?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am building an application on flutter web and have recently added a textfield to my program. A new update recently added support for scrolling with the spacebar. Is there any way to disable or intercept the spacebar to scroll feature recently implemented?
The spacebar to scroll feature can be reproduced on any scrollable list on the dev channel (for example listview)

```
Body(child:ListView(children:[TextField(),Container(height:10000,width:100)]))
```

Comment: can you please add a short reproducible code, please? Because I couldn’t able to replicate it.

Comment: @imgkl sorry! Edited the post to add the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override application shortcuts to revert to previous behavior:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final shortcuts = WidgetsApp.defaultShortcuts;
    shortcuts[LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.space)] = ActivateIntent();
    return MaterialApp(
      shortcuts: shortcuts,
      // ...
    );
  }
```

Comment: after 1 hour of searching.. you saved my life here, thanks a lot